# IF statement in select mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to use an if statement in a mysql select I know I can use if function and case, but can I achieve the same results with an if statement? can I do it without a stored procedure?

```
#IF function
SELECT *,if(productLine = 'Motorcycles','Es moto','No es moto' ) as Que_es
from products;

#Case
SELECT *,CASE WHEN productLine = 'Motorcycles' 
THEN 'Es moto' 
ELSE 'No es moto' 
END AS Que_es 
from products;

#If... i got problems here
SELECT *,IF productLine='Motorcycles' 
THEN 'Es moto' 
ELSE 'No es moto' 
END IF AS Que_es
from products;
```

Try using another nested select or try using the alias to perform the select but nothing.

Comment: What is the problem with using the `IF()` function?

Comment: Do not confuse `IF() function` with `IF statement`. The latter one can be used in compound statement (function, procedure, trigger, etc.) only.